# Multiple UITableViewCell subclasses using same xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

How can I share one `xib` among multiple `UITableViewCell` subclasses?

They all have the same view interface so I don't want to have to duplicate the same `xib` multiple times just to change the cell class.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BaseCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BaseCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BaseCell *baseCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BaseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...
```

What I need here instead is an instance of my `ChildCell` - which is a subclass of `BaseCell`. Any ideas?

Comment: Changing structure of class may be better approach. Adding states for cell and responding according to current state of cell is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use composition rather than inheritance.  Keep the 1-1 relationship between your `BaseCell` class and it's cell in the nib, add a property for an implementation object which you create and add to the cell object after you dequeue it.

Answer (score 1):

Now no way for using same `xib` for multiple cell.

But you can separate part of xib, which that all the cell will use.

And in each cell you will set a subview to this class subview, and now you can reuse this view for all cell.

You can see my image for this example:

First cell:

[image]

Second Cell:
[image]

And subview two cell use:

[image]

Now you don't need duplicate xib and can reuse this part of UI.